# Symfony 3.4: problem with POST http method Rest

Tags: php, postman, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.4, fosrestbundle

I use following libraries: JMSSerializer, FOSUserBundle FOSRestBundle + Symfony 3.4 + PHP 5
My need is to add an order to an unregistered customer( the user choose the offer and enter his info in form name email and phone number)
Customer entity has a relation OneToOne with entity User extends of FosUserBundle.

OrderController.php

```
/**
 * @rest\Post(
 *     path="/commande",
 *     name="app_commande_create"
 *       )
 * @rest\View(statusCode=Response::HTTP_CREATED)
 * @ParamConverter("commande", converter="fos_rest.request_body")
 */

public function createCommande(Commmande $commande, Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $erreur = $this->get('validator')->validate($commande);
    if (count($erreur)) {
        return $this->view($erreur, Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }$offre = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Offre')->findOneBy(['id' => $request->get('id')]);
    $client = new Customer();
    $client->getUser()->setEnabled(true);
    $client->getUser()->addRole('ROLE_CLIENT');
    $em->persist($client);
    $em->flush();
    $commande->setCustomer($client);
    $commande->setOffre($offre);
    $em->persist($commande);
    $em->flush();

}
```

This Error is returned while i test my post with postman:
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO customer () VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params [null, null, null]

Need your Help

Comment: Empty fields in INSERT? Maybe add something like `customer (field1,field2,field3)`?

Comment: thanks for your quick answer @Asken P. Yes it returns to me that it's empty despite I entered data into Body raw

Comment: {
 "date":"2020-02-22T20:25:31+00:00",
       "customer":{      
            "nom": "Michel",
            "tel": 77412569
      },
       

     "offre_id":2
}